# Add Catgory (assign) to Post Programmatically (without editing)

Tags: categories

I am looking for a way to assign (add) a category to a list of posts without editing each and every post - even by using bulk edit.

**Why?**
Because doing it manually (even using bulk) will update the published time and I do not want that.

Any idea as to how this can be done? I understand that I need an `array` of post ID:s, which I have. But how do I do this using my theme's `functions` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can set post terms programmatically with [wp_set_object_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/). There's also [wp_set_post_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/) which is a wrapper for the first function, but with some extra processing of the parameters in it.

```
foreach ( $array_of_post_ids as $post_id ) {
    // appends my-category to a post's categories
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'my-category', 'category', true );
}
```